# How to ignore search through test files

Tags: shell, command-line, ack

I am using ack and I want to avoid searching through any file which has name test. How do I do that?

Following ensures that only search through files or directory with name test. I want reverse of it.

```
ack foo --rb -G test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ack -G '^(?!test$)'
ack -G '^(?!.*test)'
```

Use the first one to ignore files named exactly `test`. Use the second to ignore files with the word `test` anywhere inside.

If you want to permanently ignore test files you could edit the `is_searchable` function in the ack script. This is the routine which filters out core dumps, swap files, and the like.

Comment: why do I need the caret sign to make it work. Based on this http://www.rubular.com/ caret is only to signify start of line.

Comment: You need to anchor the negative lookahead or else it will always match. If you just write `(?!test)` then that will match all file names because the lookahead will always be able to find *some* position where the word "test" does not exist.